# MS Access export query with DateTime extended field to csv results empty date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, export-to-csv

I have a table migrated to SQL Server. The DateTime column data type on Access is DateTime extended while in SQL Server is DateTime not DateTime2.
I run VBA code to export a query containing that DateTime Column to export that query to CSV file.

My problem is that the DateTime column cells are all empty.

Below is my VBA export code:

`DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , TableName:="qr_selected_trans_id", FileName:=fd_path & "/" & "export.csv", HasFieldNames:=True`

What am I missing?

I tried the following code in query:

`Format([DateTime_Column_Name],"mm/dd/yyyy")`

but unfortunately resulted an error in access??

```
SELECT tbl_salaries.import_transaction_id, tbl_salaries.import_tag, 
       tbl_salaries.Mobile_PK, 
       Month([Last_Active]) & "/" & Day([Last_Active]) & "/" & Year([Last_Active]) AS Last_Act, 
       tbl_salaries.Last_Active 
FROM tbl_salaries
```

Comment: Is `[DateTime_Column_Name]` actually a date? Or is it a string that looks like a date?

Comment: It is a date. based on SQL Server Column Data Type and MS Access Data Type

Comment: Maybe you could include the rest of your query? There isn't enough information here to figure out why it's blank. Does it work if you remove the format?

Comment: I rechecked it again, I think you are right. The column data type is date/time but when I made a simple query to filter on specific date it returned blank. I applied the same query but used the date filter in text format and it resulted as expected.  You are right the imported data looked like date but it has been imported as text

Comment: I changed it to dates instead of string but still same problem

Comment: Maybe you could include the rest of your query? There isn't enough information here to figure out why it's blank. Does it work if you remove the format?

Comment: SELECT tbl_salaries.import_transaction_id, tbl_salaries.import_tag, tbl_salaries.Mobile_PK, Month([Last_Active]) & "/" & Day([Last_Active]) & "/" & Year([Last_Active]) AS Last_Act, tbl_salaries.Last_Active
FROM tbl_salaries ............

Last_Act is my workaround while Last_Active is the original DateTime Field, Both are visible in Access Query Last_Act as text while Last Active as Date. The problem is when exported Excel shows Last_Active as Blank rows

Comment: I have linked SQLServer tables with date/time fields. No problem exporting to CSV and viewing in Excel. Date/time data exports without any formatting applied. But was never Date/Time Extended type.

Comment: Could try CDate() function in the query.

Comment: `Format([DateTime_Column_Name],"mm/dd/yyyy")` is the method to use. If it fails, something else is going on. Also, if you changed the data type in SQL Server, you must refresh the link in Access to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Csv can't store a date variable, it will be a string.